# Join two tables in Maria DB generating new columns

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group, mariadb-10.6

I need to join two tables in MariaDB in a specific way. For each project in table A I need to add one column for objective 1 and one column for objective 2. The value of objective 1 and objective 2 is the value of the field is_core associated with that objective in the table B in the highest phase as in the example.

In my real problem there will be more objectives but for simplicity I have used only 2 here.

Can anyone help with this? I am not very experienced with DB and my head is burning.

Table A

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | project A |
| 2 | project B |
| 3 | project C |

Table B

| id | project_id | objective | is_core | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | objective1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | objective1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | objective1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | objective2 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | objective2 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | objective2 | 0 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | objective1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | objective2 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 3 | objective1 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 3 | objective2 | 0 | 0 |

TableA.id links to TableB.projectId

Desired result:

| project_id | name | objective1 | objective2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | project A | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | project B | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | project B | 0 | 0 |

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My apologies! I have just reread your question and I obviously completely missed the explanation of the values for the objective columns. The `highest phase` requirement turns this into a fairly typical groupwise-maximum problem. Here are three of the many possible solutions.

This first query is just using two correlated subqueries in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT a.id AS project_id, a.name,
    (
        SELECT is_core
        FROM tableB
        WHERE project_id = a.id
        AND objective = 'objective1'
        ORDER BY phase DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS objective1,
    (
        SELECT is_core
        FROM tableB
        WHERE project_id = a.id
        AND objective = 'objective2'
        ORDER BY phase DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS objective2
FROM tableA a;
```

This next query uses `NOT EXISTS` to make sure we have the latest phase and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT b.project_id, a.name, 
    MAX(objective = 'objective1' AND is_core) AS objective1,
    MAX(objective = 'objective2' AND is_core) AS objective2
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.project_id
              AND NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 FROM tableB
                  WHERE project_id = b.project_id
                  AND objective = b.objective
                  AND phase > b.phase
              )
GROUP BY b.project_id;
```

This query checks the value `is_core` for the latest phase by using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT project_id, name,
    MAX(objective = 'objective1' AND is_core) AS objective1,
    MAX(objective = 'objective2' AND is_core) AS objective2
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.name, b.project_id, b.objective, b.is_core,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project_id, objective ORDER BY phase DESC) rn
    FROM tableA a
    JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.project_id
) t
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY project_id;
```

All three of these queries will *probably* perform best with a full covering index on `(project_id, objective, phase, is_core)` but should at least have an index on `(project_id, objective)`. YMMV!

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/CdKUF7dMZjV24555JAF7/4)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately is returning multiple rows for the same project id while I need only one.

Comment: @JesusParadinas: this query just cannot return multiple rows for a given project id.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM tableB 
                WHERE tableB.project_id = tableA.project_id
                   AND tableB.objective = 'objective1' ) objective1,
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM tableB 
                WHERE tableB.project_id = tableA.project_id
                   AND tableB.objective = 'objective2' ) objective2
FROM tableA;
```

If the amount of objectives (and hence the amount of final columns) is indefinite (i.e. you need in PIVOT) then use dynamic SQL.

---

> our MariaDB version is 10.6.11-MariaDB-log – Jesus Paradinas

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project_id, objective ORDER BY phase DESC) rn
  FROM B
)
SELECT A.id, A.name,
       MAX((objective = 'objective1') * (is_core)) objective1,
       MAX((objective = 'objective2') * (is_core)) objective2
FROM A
JOIN cte ON A.id = cte.project_id
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY cte.project_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/M6GMRIMH

PS. The same solution (which uses not CTE but subquery) was already provided by @nnichols..

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not working. It is not taking into acount the value isCore

Comment: @JesusParadinas Add `.. AND tableB.is_core` to each WHERE.

Comment: thanks Akina but we need to fetch the is_core value when that phase is MAX

Comment: @JesusParadinas What if maximal phase is present in 2 rows, one with is_core set and another with not set?

Comment: Akina thanks for your comments. The maximal phase can be present only once for each objective.

Comment: @JesusParadinas *The maximal phase can be present only once for each objective.* You cannot create a constraint which provides this restriction. How do you achieve the data integrity? PS. Anycase - what is your MariaDB version?

Comment: @nnichols This constraint does not provide only and definitely maximal phase to be set. It does not provide the same project/objective to have phase to be both set and dropped even.

Comment: our MariaDB version is 10.6.11-MariaDB-log

Answer (score 1):

You can make two left join, one for objective1 and the other for objective2.

```
SELECT tableA.id AS project_id,
       tableA.name,
       MAX(tableB.is_core) AS "objective1",
       MAX(tableB2.is_core) AS "objective2"
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.project_id = tableA.id AND tableB.objective = "objective1"
LEFT JOIN tableB AS tableB2 ON tableB2.project_id = tableA.id AND tableB2.objective = "objective2"
GROUP BY tableA.id
```

Comment: looks good but the max() function should go with the "phase" column, and for that row where the phase is maximum take the is_core value for that objective.

Comment: I see, is the maximum value of phase column will always have maximum value of is_core column? or is there any possibilities that maximum value of phase column have not the maximum value of is_core value column?

Comment: we need the is_core value when the phase is maxium, for each objective type in a new column for each objective.